# Составить SQL-запрос для подсчета NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть примерная таблица:

```
School  TestResult
Школа 1      55
Школа 2      26
Школа 1      34
Школа 3      30 
Школа 4      10
```

Нужно вывести таблицу, в которой указано сколько раз школа набрала тестовый балл **выше 20**, если нет, то необходимо указать **ноль!** Вот как раз с этим нулем и проблемы, ведь агрегатные функции не считают NULL. Вообщем нужно получить вот это:

```
School        count
Школа 1         2
Школа 2         1
Школа 3         1
Школа 4         0
```

Перепробовал разного рода запросы, но все попытке счетны. Эксперементировал с CASE, ISNULL, SUM ничего не получается. Вот одна из последних попыток:

```
select school, count(school), SUM(CASE WHEN school IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
from school
where TestResult > 20
group by school
```

Ответ:

```
  Школа 1         2
  Школа 2         1
  Школа 3         1
```

Т.е. **Школа 4** не коем образом не отображается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT School, SUM(CASE WHEN TestResult > 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count
FROM School
GROUP BY School
```